# why don't i get return value in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Why don't I get the result of this query in MySQL?

```
SELECT * FROM feature_product 
INNER JOIN `product` on product.`product_id`=product_ref_id
WHERE  ( feature_ref_id=11 or feature_ref_id=10  ) AND ( feature_ref_id=13 or feature_ref_id=13  )
```

Comment: Because `feature_ref_id` cannot be (11 or 10) and 13 at the same time.

Comment: Read the `WHERE` clause carefully. It says the value of `feature_ref_id` must be either `10` or `11` but, on the same time, it must be `13` as well. I don't know any value that can be equal to `10` and `13` on the same time. Do you?

Comment: Replace `And` with `Or` and it will work.

Comment: I suspect that you're after something slightly different. But it would be useful to be sure. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM feature_product 
INNER JOIN `product` on product.`product_id`=product_ref_id where 
feature_ref_id   NOT IN("10","11","13");
```

you will get the desired out put using this query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM feature_product fp

INNER JOIN product p on p.product_id=fp.product_ref_id

WHERE feature_ref_id in  (11,10,13)

Please try above and it will be great if you share both table column name.

Comment: it is not working beacuse  IN equal OR , I get result (11 OR 10) AND 13       ,this result  is (11 OR 10 OR 13)

Comment: SELECT * FROM feature_product fp

INNER JOIN product p on p.product_id=fp.product_ref_id

WHERE feature_ref_id in (11,10) and  feature_ref_id in (13) 

Use above and let me know if it works